# MongoDB geospatial query returns null array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial

I'm testing a geospatial query against both of my development and production environments. Production server is a digital ocean VPS server. The query works fine in development machine, However, at production it returns a null array. However, when I executed the query straight from the MONGO shell of the production server, it does returns the results. Following is the query function

```
exports.nearby=function(req,res){

      var lat= +req.params.lat,
          long= +req.params.long,
          distance = +req.params.radius,
          cat = req.query.cat || 'auditorium';

      Item.find({
        "loc": {
          $near: {
            $geometry: {
              type: "Point",
              coordinates: [long,lat]
            },
            $maxDistance: distance
          }
        },
        category: cat
      }, function(err,data){
        err ? res.json(err) : res.json(data);
      });

}
```

**development environments**

Local Machine:
    Ubuntu 14.04, node: v0.10.29, MongoDB: 2.6.4

Production:
    ubuntu 14.04, node: v0.10.30, MongoDB: 2.6.5

Any help much appreciated...thanks

Comment: What is the name of the collection you are querying in the shell? You realize mongoose pluralizes the model name as the collection name right?

Comment: how are you executing the query? is it inside of an express app? my guess is that your production environment environment variables or server configuration is different...

Comment: @NeilLunn the collection name is `items`. yes, I know mongoose will pluralize the model name `item` for the collection

Comment: @gabereal Yes, I'm executing from an express app as API call. I double checked the environment variables for production, and what so strange is all other API calls executes as the way it expected to be on the production server.

Comment: @Jasnan Try debugging your app, check the values for lat, long in console log, in your above code

Comment: @Ravi all parameters (long, lat, radius, category) are printing to the console, but still the return is a null array.

Comment: @Jasnan and what about `data` and `err`, what do they print?

Comment: @Ravi `data` is `[]` and `err` is `null`.

Comment: @Jasnan have you tried upgrading your local version of node and mongo so that you have the exact same setup as your production server. this probably isn't the problem, but it's worth a shot...

Comment: @gabereal Yes, I did upgrade local version to the same as the production version. But problem still continues...

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the index2d in the production database?? Is it the same database?

This works fine for me:

```
var options = { $and:[{location : { $near : [longitude, latitude], $maxDistance : distance/111.12}}]};
User.find(options, '_id location').exec(function (err, users) {
```